# Why am I getting a compiler error?

Tags: errors, algorithms

```
\begin{algorithm}  
  \label{alg:1}  
  \begin{algorithmic}[1] %here [1] says use line numbers every 1 line  
    \INPUT Array $A$ %use math mode liberally  
    \OUTPUT Integer value that repeats in $A$  
    \FORALL {$a \in A$}    
    \FORALL{$b \in A$}    
    \IF {$$A[a]$$ $\equiv$ $$A[b]$$}  
    \RETURN $$A[a]$$  
    \ENDIF  
    \ENDFOR  
    \RETURN No values repeat  
  \end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm}
```

produces the

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{ALC@g} on input line 74 ended by \end{algori
thmic}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.81       \end{algorithmic}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your usage of `$$` is wrong.

Comment: I've not tried to compile because I'm not sure what packages you're using, but you have two `\FORALL` and only one `\ENDFOR`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are using \FORALL wrong.

It should be

```latex
\FORALL{<condition>} \STATE{<text>} \ENDFOR
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms